# Representing version number as regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I need to represent version numbers as regular expressions. The broad definition is

1. Consist only of numbers
2. Allow any number of decimal points (but not consecutively)
3. No limit on maximum number

So `2.3.4.1,2.3,2,9999.9999.9999` are all valid whereas `2..,2.3.` is not.

I wrote the following simple regex

```
'(\d+\.{0,1})+'
```

Using it in python with [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module and searching in '2.6.31' gives

```
>>> y = re.match(r'(\d+\.{0,1})+$','2.6.31')
>>> y.group(0)
'2.6.31'
>>> y.group(1)
'31'
```

But if I name the group, then the named group only has 31.

Is my regex representation correct or can it be tuned/improved? It does not currently handle the `2.3.` case.

Comment: The capture group will only keep the last occurrence of a pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notation `{0,1}` can be shortened to just `?`:

```
r'(\d+\.?)+$'
```

However, the above will allow a trailing `.`. Perhaps try:

```
r'\d+(\.\d+)*$'
```

Once you have validated the format matches what you expect, the easiest way to get the numbers out is with `re.findall()`:

```
>>> ver = "1.2.3.4"
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', ver)
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you might want to use [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/):

```
>>> from pyparsing import *
>>> integer = Word(nums)
>>> parser = delimitedList(integer, delim='.') + StringEnd()
>>> list(parser.parseString('1.2.3.4'))
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

or [lepl](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/):

```
>>> from lepl import *
>>> with Separator(~Literal('.')):
...    parser = Integer()[1:]
>>> parser.parse('1.2.3.4')
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: This pattern `something + ZeroOrMore(Suppress(delimiter) + something` is so common, pyparsing provides the helper function `delimitedList`, allowing you to write your parser as just  `parser=delimitedList(integer, delim='.')` and get the same results.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I've updated my answer. Thanks a lot not only for your comment, but also for pyparsing.