# Find only integer value where you have multiple strings in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below piece of code in python which I am using to get the component name of the JIRA issue some of them are single value in component field and some of them are multiple values in component field. My issue is that component field could have values with different name e.g  R ABC 1.1 , R Aiapara 2.3A1(Active) etc.I don't want to do the way I am trying to do in below code.Is there any way I can find only the integer value from the component. from this component(R ABC 1.1) I need 1.1 and for 2nd component (R Aiapara 2.3A1(Active) I need 2.3 as well so this I would not need to depend on the name of the component

```
  for version in issue["fields"]["components"]:
    cacheData = json.dumps(version)
    jsonToPython = json.loads(cacheData)
    if jsonToPython['name'][:10] == "R Aiapara ": 
      allModules.append(jsonToPython["name"][10:])
      print allModules
```

Below is the output I am getting

```
Retrieving list of issues
Processing SPTN-2
[u'1.6']
Processing SPTN-1
[u'1.5']
[u'1.5', u'1.6']
```

Comment: Did you mean the _numeric_ part? `4.4` Is not an integer. Or rather the "version number", i.e. also stuff like `4.4.4` which is not even numeric?

Comment: `int()` can you use that???

Comment: @tobias_k  yes that numeric part I need

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis can u give me an example how cloud I achieve this in above scenario?

Comment: In this case, try regex like here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8816302/1639625

Answer (score 3):

Using regex:

```
import re
s1 = "R ABC 4.4"
s2 = "R Ciapara 4.4A1(Active)"

print(re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+", s1))
print(re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+", s2))
```

**Output:**

```
['4.4']
['4.4']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I feel like I am not quite understanding your question, so I will try to answer as best I can, but feel free to correct me if I get anything wrong.

This function will get all the numbers from the string in a list:

```
def getNumber(string):
    numbers = ".0123456789"
    result = []
    isNumber = False
    for i in string:
        if (i in numbers and isNumber):
            result[-1] += i
        elif i in result:
            result+= [i]
            isNumber = True
        else:
            isNumber = False

    return result
```

However, if you want all the characters after the first number, then you will want this function. It will return everything after the first number, and False if there isn't a number there.

```
def getNumber(string):
    numbers = ".0123456789"
    result = []
    isNumber = False
    for i,char in enumerate(string):
        if char in numbers:
            return string[i:]
    return False
```

Now, if you want everything between the first and last numbers, then try this one instead:

```
def getNumber(string):
    numbers = ".0123456789"
    result = string
    isNumber = False
    for i,char in enumerate(string):
        if char in numbers:
            result = result[i:]
            break
    for i in range(len(result)-1, 0, -1):
        if result[i] in numbers:
            result = result[:i+1]
            break

    return result
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your response